# django download files from a list (s3 as back-end)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, boto3

I need to list an html table the content of a S3 bucket and enable the option to download the file. To do so I have done he following:
The code shows the list of the bucket files correctly, but I'm not sure how I can write the code to download the files.

inventory.html:

```
{% block title %} title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date&nbsp;<a href="?order_by=ord_date&direction=desc">{% load static %}<img src="{% static "arrow.png" %}" width="12" height="12" alt="order desc"></a><a href="?order_by=ord_date&direction=asc">{% load static %}<img src="{% static "sort-down.png" %}" width="12" height="12" alt="order asc"></a></th>

      <th scope="col">Name&nbsp;<a href="?order_by=ord_source&direction=desc">{% load static %}<img src="{% static "arrow.png" %}" width="12" height="12" alt="order desc"></a><a href="?order_by=ord_source&direction=asc">{% load static %}<img src="{% static "sort-down.png" %}" width="12" height="12" alt="order asc"></a></th>

      <th scope="col">Size</th>

      <th scope="col">Action</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
     {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.LastModified }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Key }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Size }}</td>
          <td><button type="Button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><a href="?key_download={{ item.Key }}">Download</button></a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')

def inventory(request):
    if request.GET.get('key_download'):
        url = client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = { 
                                                                    'Bucket':'url_of_the_bucket',
                                                                    'Key':request.GET.get('key_download')},
                                                          ExpiresIn = 86400)

        return **"I don't know how I can return it"**
    else:
        fdc_inventories = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='url_of_the_bucket')
        fdc_inventories['Contents'].sort(key=itemgetter('LastModified'), reverse=True)
        return render(request, 'inventory.html', {'items': fdc_inventories['Contents']})
```

So I'm not sure how I can return it. 
Bear in mind that the list on the template or html contain a list of the object and it is not a static content.

Any other way to do it, I appreciate a lot.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a redirect, with right ACL it should start the download

    `return HttpResponseRedirect(url)`